# Vagrant behind cooporate proxy

Tags: proxy, vagrant, virtualbox

I installed vagrant with an Ubuntu box. The host running is working behind a cooperate proxy. I installed the `vagrant-proxyconf (1.5.1)` and added the proxy data to the `Vagrantfile` as such

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    config.proxy.http     = "proxy:port"
    config.proxy.https    = "proxy:port"
    config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
  end
end
```

But when I ssh into the vagrantbox and do `sudo apt-get update` It just throws out errors.

One of the errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Cannot initiate the connection to 3128:80 (0.0.12.56). - connect (22: Invalid argument
```

My gut tells me something is wrong with the ports out look at 3128:80, any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you in advance for your answer, all help appreciated!!!

Comment: Should "proxy:port" in your code snippet actually be the proxy address and port? "h ttp://myproxy.madeup.com:80" for example?

Comment: Yes @Disco my actual proxy is written there. It is on port 3128..

Comment: Phew, just checking :-)

Comment: When I had a similar issue, it was that the sudo session didn't pick up the proxy. I had to add a line to /etc/sudoers to keep the proxy (http://askubuntu.com/questions/7470/how-to-run-sudo-apt-get-update-through-proxy-in-commandline). I think I used vagrant to do that, but don't have time to check currently. Hopefully that may help.

Comment: You can check if that is the issue by trying to wget something from archive.ubuntu.com and then trying to sudo wget it. The latter will fail if that's the issue